# Unmap accented characters

Tags: key-bindings, gvim

If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, it prints `ï`. I would prefer it not do
anything. I tried these:

```
:unmap <M-o>
:iunmap <M-o>
```

but it just says:

```
E31: No such mapping
```

From the comments, I have also tried these:

```
gvim -u NONE -N
gvim --clean
```

and I tried the release without runtime files as well:

https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim82.zip

also `set keymap` returns `keymap=`.

Comment: These are not Vim mappings, but they're defined by your O.S.'s keyboard driver. You can probably check that by using the same combination on another application... You can possibly change your O.S.'s settings (or keyboard layout) so it doesn't produce those characters, but that's out of this scope of Vi & Vim... Try [Superuser SE](superuser.com) perhaps...

Comment: How about `:iunmap <M-o>`, does that do anything?

Comment: Vim on terminal or gVim? Are you sure it's not your terminal or something? Vim doesn't do this by default... So unless you have a vimrc from someone else that sets this up (and it doesn't look like you do), not sure how to explain this.

Comment: Try `gvim -u NONE -N` or `gvim --clean` or similar, as well... Also, I think there might be something on Windows about keyboard layouts per application, so maybe that's why you see this on gVim and not notepad?

Comment: Does `:set keymap?` return anything? If it's set, that might explain it (perhaps...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for upper and lower:

```
imap <M-O> <Nop>
imap <M-o> <Nop>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a normal behaviour of gui flavours of vim like gvim. `<m-i>`, `<a-i>` and `é` are the same thing.

Usually people aren't bothered by meta+key inserting an accentuated character, but the other way around. See the very old issue with French people needing to insert `é` in LaTeX document which in turn triggers `\item` insertion (IIRC) with vim-latex.

My opinion on the subject: don't bother with it and learn not to type `<m-o>` needlessly.

PS: while I was looking for the recent discussion I've seen in my mailbox on this topic, I've found the vim [issue # 5644](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:q4EcJkfOtEMJ:https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5644) that OP has probably initiated (given the timestamps). Why is this question active today?